# implementing a loop using final variables

Tags: java, variables, loops, static, final

Is there a way to implement a loop using final variables? 
I mean a loop that would run for a specified number of iterations when you are not allowed to change anything after initialization!

Comment: Your question is unclear...

Comment: Heck, it could be as easy as `for (final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0); i.get() < MAX; i.incrementAndGet())`. Final variables don't mean immutable objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is recursion allowed, or do you literally need a loop construct like `for` or `while`? If you can use recursion, then:

```
void loop(final int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    System.out.println("Count: " + n);
    loop(n-1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create an `Iterable<Integer>` class representing an arbitrary range (without actually having to store all of the values in a list):

```
public static class FixedIntRange implements Iterable<Integer> {
    private final int min;
    private final int max;

    public FixedIntRange(final int min, final int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
            private Integer next = FixedIntRange.this.min;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return next != null;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                final Integer ret = next;
                next = ret == max ? null : next + 1;
                return ret;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and then iterate over it normally:

```
for (final int i : new FixedIntRange(-10, 20)) {
    // this will be run for each i in the range [-10, 20]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
final int max = 5;
for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {}
```

Or another interesting one-

```
final boolean flag = true;
while(flag) {
   // keep doing your stuff and break after certain point
}
```

One more-

```
List<String> list = ......
for(final Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
}
```

Comment: Nor sure if `i` or `flag` doesn't brake the rule "you are not allowed to change anything after initialization"

Answer (score 0):

Create an array whose size is the required number of iterations, then use it in a for-each loop:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int N = 20;
    final int[] control = new int[N];
    for(final int i : control){
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

The trick here is that the iteration indexing is generated by the compiler as part of the enhanced for statement, and does not use any user-declared variable.